# Unable to download pyssdeep

Tags: svn

I am using the following command as specified in various documentations online as part of the installation for Cuckoo sandbox on Ubuntu:

```
svn checkout http://pyssdeep.googlecode.com/svn/trunk pyssdeep
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
 svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://pyssdeep.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E160013: '/svn/trunk' path not found
```

Looking for assistance on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Code was closed some time ago. All of the projects had to be migrated to other services, but it seems that this particular https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyssdeep/ was not migrated.

It means that the Subversion repository is not available anymore and the project's history perished too (thanks Google).

The only option to get the code of the project now is to download it as Subversion working copy archive https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/pyssdeep/source-archive.zip

Note that Google Code archive offers a super old working copy to download and if you use up-to-date Subversion client, you have to run `svn upgrade` to begin working with it.